# Soft Navigation Bar Overlays App in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In Android Lollipop (most recent dev preview, build LPX13D) on my Nexus 5, an app I am writing seems to be hidden below the soft navigation bar (the bar with Back, Home, and App History buttons). I cannot duplicate this on a Nexus 4 running Kit Kat (nothing gets hidden behind the navigation bar).

What do I have to do shrink the app's viewport so that all of my content can be seen on screen?

EDIT:

Screenshots, as requested.

Nexus 4 running Kit Kat (4.4.4):
[image]

Nexus 5 running Lollipop (5.0, LPX13D):
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a ton of testing, I have discovered it is an issue with the SlidingMenu library. I wasn't able to fix it nor was I able to find a root cause other than it involving the option to slide the action bar.

I have posted an issue on the library's GitHub to hopefully get either a fix to the library or a solution.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680

**EDIT (2014-11-04):** As a quick follow up, a user posted in the above issue that it is related to the Material theme and that using the Holo theme will avoid this issue. I was able to confirm this. So we will likely need to wait for a fix to SlidingMenu before using it with the Material theme.

Comment: I added a new comment there with fix of other kind. See https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680#issuecomment-66604727

Comment: This solution from @DenRimus left a bottom gap when the device have a hardware Navigation Bar. I prefer this one that works both Software and Hardware Navigation Bar.   "if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
 setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);"     https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680#issuecomment-73912402

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root view in your Activity layout file.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I tried it in several different activities with different layouts and it didn't work on any of them. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Can you post perhaps a cropped image of the Nexus 5 and Nexus 4 so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Is the NavigationBar transparent?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I uploaded the requested screenshots to the question (altered only actionbar to remove identifying logo since app is unfinished). Both scrollviews are scrolled to the very bottom, but it happens in all view types. And no, I am not using a transparent NavigationBar. Thanks again for looking at this.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for similar bug in OLD version of android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Answer (score 0):

If someone has similar problem with android.support.v4 - just update Support Library to 22.2.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours R&D here we go with the solution

If you are using `ResideMenu` library then it can be fixed by just adding this method in `ResideMenu.java`

```
  @Override
protected boolean fitSystemWindows(Rect insets) {
    int bottomPadding = insets.bottom;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            bottomPadding += resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
    }
    this.setPadding(viewActivity.getPaddingLeft() + insets.left, viewActivity.getPaddingTop() + insets.top,
            viewActivity.getPaddingRight() + insets.right, viewActivity.getPaddingBottom() + bottomPadding);
    insets.left = insets.top = insets.right = insets.bottom = 0;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simple solution that is working for me for now is,
Get Navigation bar height and set padding to root layout of activity in OnCreate() after setContentView.

```
.....
        int navHeight = getNavHeight();
        if (navHeight > 0) {
            (findViewById(R.id.rlMain)).setPadding(0, 0, 0, navHeight);
        }
.....
    private int getNavHeight() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            return 0;
        try {

            Resources resources = getResources();
            int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(getApplicationContext()).hasPermanentMenuKey();
                boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

                if (!hasMenuKey && !hasBackKey) {
                    return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```